IoT devices simulator, power consumption
I need an IoT simulator or something similar in order to measure power consumption for different crypto algorithms.
All I have to do is to succeed a basic simulation execution for a specific platform (ex. Mica2, Micaz), and then to progress by adding some crypto algorithms (encryption, digital signature etc.).
I don't know if there are simulators or platforms which I can do this stuff on...
I have tried to install TinyOS on Ubuntu 18.04, but I saw in some kind of article that power consumption can be measured/modeled with the help of an extension called PowerTOSSIM.
I didn't manage to make TinyOS basic simulations work, neither PowerTOSSIM, as it was used a long time ago...
